# Full domain .htaccess 301 keeping same paths, but also redirect some URLs to different paths

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I believe the following code will redirect my old domain to my new domain keeping the same URL paths.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.co.uk 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I also have some URLS from my old site that don't exist on my new site, so they would return a 404 with the rule above.

How do I redirect these to an alternative URL path?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to redirect these specific URLs *before* your catch-all redirect above. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-does-not-exist$ /new-url-that-does-exist [R=301,L]
```

Just to note... in `.htaccess` there is no slash prefix on the source URL pattern, ie. the regex `^old-url-does-not-exist$` matches the URL `/old-url-does-not-exist`. Whereas there is a slash prefix on the destination URL. That's just `RewriteRule` syntax.